# Ubuntu does not use Nvidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

I got Ubuntu 20 with 5.7.9 kernel and nvidia-smi 450.57 drivers on Laptop with AMD integrated graphic and gtx 1660 ti but it seems like integrated graphic is used for everything.
Output from `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.57       Driver Version: 450.57       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P8     3W /  N/A |     11MiB /  5944MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1221      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2466      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The 5.7.9 kernel is not supported. There is no Ubuntu 20.

Comment: @Bless if you try `sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1` what do you get after? `nvidia-smi`??